# Traduction de « from the horse's mouth »

Tags: traduction, anglais

Comment traduire en français l'expression anglaise  « from the horse's mouth »?

Comment: @Montéedelait Je me demande vraiment ce qui tout d'un coup vous fait trouver cette question mauvaise?

Comment: @Montéedelait Ahhhh! Voilà une bonne remarque (qui ne correspond pas (vr bounty))! Ce que l'on aurait voulu lire dans une réponse! (+3)! (Au lieu de cela c'est dans du pinaillage, dommage)

Comment: J'ai déjà rencontré l'expression *(fraîchement) tiré du puits*, notamment en Alsace, pour parler d'une information donnée par une personne qu'elle concerne directement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***De source sûre***, mais sans le côté humoristique...

Il n'existe pas d'expression toute faite en français qui corresponde exactement à *from the horse's mouth*.

Avec un contexte complet, on peut essayer de trouver une expression qui s'approche mieux de l'esprit original.

Voici par exemple, une réplique culte du cinéma français :

> César: —  Mais enfin, tout le monde le sait que tu es cocu, c'est pas un mystère, ça !
>   Escartefigue: — Monsieur Brun ne le savait pas !
>   César: —  Eh, **c'est lui qui me l'a dit** ! voyons.

Marcel Pagnol, *Marius*, La partie de carte, 1931

Comment: Oui, en passant à un registre courant c'est une expression parfaite et éventuellement ça pourrait être un choix à faire; j'ai appris que « from the horse's mouth » est une expression assez informelle en anglais et je pensais surtout à un équivalent dans le même registre avec peut être l'amusant en plus.

Comment: Je ne pense pas qu'il existe de traduction toute faite qui corresponde exactement à *from the horse's mouth*. Avec un contexte complet, on peut essayer de trouver une expression qui colle mieux à l'esprit original.

Answer (score 3):

Un dictionnaire anglais-français de qualité moyenne ou mieux nous indique que *« (straight) from the horse’s mouth »* se traduit par...

> de source sûre

C’est dans une certaine mesure faire abstraction de la définition offerte par les dictionnaires anglais :

> From the person directly concerned or another authoritative source.

La source sûre peut être invoquée sans être nommée. On peut avoir à se fier à la parole de la personne quant à sa valeur.

*« The horse’s mouth »*, en contrepartie, est une information ***de première main***. Je ne saurais dire que je possède des informations de première main concernant une certaine personne et cacher ma source. On pourra vérifier, ou de dénégations de la première main en question pourraient rapidement suivre mes déclarations si je mens. On pourrait en ceci l’opposer aux *rumeurs, on-dit, entendus-dire* et autres *bruits qui courent*, ou à des expressions comme *« l’homme qui a vu l’homme qui a vu l’ours »* et des filiations généalogiques compliquées comme on en entend parfois, du style *« j’ai appris de la sœur de l’ex-mari de ma cousine au troisième degré, qui m’a affirmé que c’était arrivé à la tante de l’amie de sa première copine » (c'était sans doute il y a longtemps et loin d’ici, d’ailleurs...)*.

Ou alors, *« the horse’s mouth »* est celle de spécialistes reconnus d’un sujet. Point besoin alors de demeurer dans le vague d’une source sûre. Si l’anonymat doit néanmoins être préservé, on aurait malgré tout avantage à parler « d’un ou une spécialiste reconnus en la matière ». Si l’on présente un invité qui nous parlera du sujet, donner la longue séquence de ses qualifications peut être une option, mais ce n’est malheureusement ni concis, ni coloré.

---

#### Et la fantaisie, alors ?

Comment introduire une touche d’humour dans la présentation de l’information de première main ? On pourra, si c’est le cas, insister davantage sur la prise d’information *à chaud*, ou la cueillette *à vif*. On pourrait alors invoquer des traces physiques évanescentes, qui apparaissent lors d’une activité mais disparaissent rapidement après. L’idée de première main sera alors intrinsèquement incluse, puisque la source possédait les attributs possibles ou imaginaires de l’activité. En utilisant des images un peu absurdes, il reste possible de demeurer dans le bon goût (ou pas). Au hasard de circonstances particulières imaginées ici et maintenant, où l’information d’intérêt serait fournie par :

- *Une astronaute qui rentre de mission :*

  - La gravité ne lui était pas encore complètement revenue: elle flottait encore un peu au-dessus du sol quand je lui ai parlé.
  - C’est vous dire : elle n’était pas encore revenue sur Terre après ce séjour en orbite.
- *Un explorateur revenant de l’Antarctique :*

  - Il avait encore des glaçons qui lui pendait du nez quand il m’a relaté que...
  - Il faisait encore de la buée en parlant lors de notre entrevue.
- *Un boxeur après un combat âprement disputé :*

  - De sa bouche ensanglantée et d’une voix encore pleine de bulles et de gargouillis il nous a commenté cette épique rencontre.

Pour une autorité reconnue, on pourrait invoquer un agenda chargé :

- Entre une conférence à Münich et une campagne de terrain chargée qu’il partagera entre Hawaii et l’Indonésie, Roch Desgranites nous a consacré une petite demi-heure pour nous  parler de la tectonique des plaques.